# Neural Network: A Perceptron for guessing the position of a point relative to a function

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

I am building a simple Perceptron with 3 inputs (x, y, bias=1)

He must guess whether the given point (x,y) is ***under*** or ***below*** a given function.

Basically, it's was inspired by [this article](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-10-neural-networks/)

A supervised model of learning is used to train the network and the formula is the following:

```
learningConst = 0.01
error = desired - neuralAnswer
new_weights[i] = old_weights[i] + error * inputs[i] * learningConst
```

Still, after *100000* training tests it makes mistakes even on a simple function (2x+1)

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n #n is 2 in this case. 2 inputs [ x, y ] 
        self.weights = [np.random.uniform(-1, 1) for x in range(n)]
        self.learningConstant = 0.05

    # 1 added to the sum is the bias input    
    def feedForward(self, inputs):
        return 1 + sum([self.weights[i]*inputs[i] for i in range(self.n)])

    def activate(self, result):
        if result >= 0:
            return 1
        elif result < 0:
            return -1

    def train(self, inputs, expected):
        prediction = self.feedForward(inputs)
        answer = self.activate(prediction)
        error = expected - answer

        self.weights = [
            self.weights[i] + error * inputs[i] * self.learningConstant 
            for i in range(self.n)
        ]
        #print(self.weights)

    def predict(self, inputs):
        prediction = self.feedForward(inputs)
        return self.activate(prediction)
```

You can see here the results. Green color indicates that the perceptron guessed it right and the red ones indicate the mistakes.
Funny thing - it tends to mistake on points below the line.

What should I do to improve the program?

[image: Perceptron results]

**THE FULL CODE** : [CLICK](http://pastie.org/10836760)

***SOLUTION***

My problem was using the bias input as a brute constant (line 14 of the full code) without allowing the algorithm to learn on it.
So, my inputs now are [bias, x, y] and the weights are [w1, w3, w3] - the bias input now has its weight.

Another good idea is to save the weights somewhere else, so the algorithm doesn't have to start over each time you test the program.

**2x + 1**
[image]

**x^2 - 2x + 1**
[image]

Comment: I don't see the point of using `numpy` only to produce random numbers... use numpy arrays and vector operations: `self.weigths = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=n)` and also `np.sum(self.weigths * inputs)` and `self.weights = self.weights + error*inputs*self.learningConstant`.

Comment: Can you please post the code that also uses your `Perceptron` so that I don't have to make it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your solution is that your bias is always 1. It's not a parameter - it's constant. So this might be a problem because your model is pretty much weaker than classical perceptron model.

Comment: That's a good idea! The bias input might change the answer. But, shoudn't the neural network adapt it's weights to the bias input after some tests?

Comment: Yes, it should, but no matter how they will adapt your bias will always be positive. This may seriously harm your prediction.

Comment: How should I change it? I have tried to take it off and lower it to 0.01 - practiacally no effect

Comment: Try using -1. Or better - simply change your weights to be three dimensional [w1, w2, w3], and make your input to be [1,x,y]. Then, without bias it should work well.

Comment: But, what if there is another function? Is there any generic bias input?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko
What is we and w? 
Did you mean that the weight of one connection should be a list of 3 numbers?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko
Right now I have [x, y]  and [w1, w2]. So I should add the bias part and update it as well when training

Comment: Wow! I've made [bias, x, y] and [w1, w2, w3] and it seems to work!

Comment: Yes. Exactly. And in this case hardcoded 1 is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the data you wish to classify is linearly separable or the perceptron learning algorithm will never converge.

Comment: You should pick a misclassified example at random and update the weight with the answer (which is wrong). Indeed if you multiply for each example it won't work.

Comment: I updated the response because it looks like the update with the error was correct. To have a linearly separable set of random points generate a random set of positive examples and a random set of negative examples for instance

Comment: I mean...if I have a set of random 2D points - it is always separable by a line (at least one vertical line is always viable)

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate the statement about generation a separable set of tests?

Comment: @DenisRozimovschii Your training set is fine since by their definition they will either be on or above the line, or below, hence separable by a line

Comment: @bakkal
Maybe I need to increase the number of training tests?
But...the weights don't seem to converge to some value, the always change